# Laravel - Como salvar escolha de checkbox em listagem de itens?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Em um sistema de gerenciamento de contato, tenho umas listagem de itens os quais tem um checkbox cada um(estilo gmail) para que eu possa seleciona-los e utilizar alguma ação relacionada aos selecionados. Qual a melhor forma de salvar esses itens selecionados a cada página acessada?

Um dos **Controllers** que lista os itens:

```
$request = DB::table('contatos')
            ->select('*')
            ->paginate(15);

        return view('list')
            ->with('request', $request);
```

E a **View**:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="seleciona_todos" /></th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach($r as $p)
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{ $p->id }}" /></td>
        <td>{{ $p->nome }}</td>
        <td>{{ $p->email }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach

    </table>
    {!! $r->appends(Input::except('page'))->links(); !!}
```

**- Tem paginação**

**- Utilizo o Laravel**

**- Terá outras contas de usuários admin mexendo ao mesmo tempo**

Já pensei em fazer um ajax para um arquivo php que grava e exclui itens de um array em uma sessão ou até mesmo utilizar uma tabela no banco de dados para gravar os itens selecionados atualmente(porém terá outros usuários mexendo no momento e acho q isso não ia dar certo). 
Qual o melhor jeito de resolver isso?

Comment: Se vc quer ver as modificações em real-time pusher e Laravel echo

Comment: vc pode fazer assim no seu input: `<input type="checkbox" name="selecionados[]" value="{{$p->id}}">`e capturar o array:  $dataForm = $request->all();

dd($dataForm['selecionados']), o `dd()`  deve retornar um `var_dump` do laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito não haver problemas em utilizar o banco de dados e ajax mesmo que tendo outros usuários mexendo no momento. Se esse for o problema você pode utilizar `DB::transaction()` no método que executa a ação de excluir os itens.

Por exemplo:

```
DB::transaction(function(){

  // ação de deletar, inserir e etc

});
```

caso ocorra algum erro nesta ação o sistema não efetuará a mudança no banco de dados.